# SQL - truncating (Oracle) dates - what is a future safe option?

Tags: sql

We are using the Oracle TRUNC() sql function to truncate dates. The column has type DATE.

What is a good and future proof option for truncating dates? Chances are that we are going to migrate to Postgress or MySql.

Example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM KIB_IND_SNAPSHOT
WHERE snsh_id IN (SELECT MAX(snsh_id)
                  FROM KIB_IND_SNAPSHOT
                  WHERE SNSH_STATUS = 'SUCCES'
                  GROUP BY TRUNC(SNSH_TIJDST_ONTST)
                 )
ORDER BY SNSH_TIJDST_ONTST;
```

Comment: You will need to do work to translate the code to another database.  This applies not only to functions but to the structure of queries and to any scripting code that you have.

Comment: OK, understand. What is the 'good' way for the the above SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Universal date format i.e. YYYY-MM-DD which will future proof it(as of now :) ).Please refer following URL https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime for details.

Update : BTW the answer I gave is for scenario where you want to migrate your DB to other Database. Following this will give you less headache

Comment: OK, can you show how to appy this to the SQL example in the question?